# How to install libav-tools in centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, libav

I used tutorial to compile it from source but it never worked for me.
I am facing error on following points

Download x264 codec and compile it:

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git x264
cd x264
./configure –enable-static
make && make install
```

**error log:**

```
 cd x264
     ./configure –enable-static
    Unknown option –enable-static, ignored
    Found no assembler
    Minimum version is yasm-1.2.0
    If you really want to compile without asm, configure with --disable-asm.
      make && make install
    Makefile:3: config.mak: No such file or directory
    ./configure
    Found no assembler
    Minimum version is yasm-1.2.0
    If you really want to compile without asm, configure with --disable-asm.
    make: *** [config.mak] Error 1
```

and

```
cd libav
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
make && make install
```

**error log:**

```
 cd libav
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
Unable to create and execute files in /tmp.  Set the TMPDIR environment
variable to another directory and make sure that it is not mounted noexec.
Sanity test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
libav-tools@libav.org mailing list or IRC #libav on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
  make && make install
Makefile:1: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:99: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:137: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:137: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:139: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:214: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
```

Reference Link:
http://blog.droidzone.in/2013/12/24/convert-a-wmv-file-to-avi-on-the-linux-command-line/

---

I installed using these but still i am facing issues

```
wget https://www.libav.org/releases/libav-10.5.tar.gz
tar xf libav-10.5.tar.gz
TMPDIR=/home/sociaow2/tmp/avco/libav-10.5 ./configure
make && make install
cd
```

All libs installed now when i enter that command

```
 avconv -i state.mp4  -r 20 -s 480x352 -b 600k  -vcodec libx264 out_state.mp4
```

Unknown encoder 'libx264'
 on command

```
  avconv -i state.mp4  -r 20 -s 480x352 -b 600k  -vcodec libx264 out_state.mp4
```

Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
on command

```
 avconv -i state.mp4  -r 20 -s 480x352 -b 600k  -vcodec libx264 out_state.mp4
```

Comment: From the error log, you need to install an assembler (e.g. `yasm`), or compile with the `--disable-asm` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing `--enable-libx264` from your configure line and your server is configured disabling executing in `/tmp` I suggest you to do something like

`mkdir ~/tmp
export TMPDIR=~/tmp
./configure --enable-gnu --enable-libx264`

(further info [here](https://wiki.libav.org/Encoding/h264))

Installing yasm is required by x264 as stated above.

Make sure you have `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH since you are installing yasm, x264 and libav there.

Answer (score 1):

--enable-static    (need to have double dash)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issue when I tried to setup ffmpeg on my vps at [rosehosting](https://www.rosehosting.com/). The rosehosting support fixed the issue and explained to me that I needed higher *yasm* version to compile the latest x264 version. They used the following steps to install yasm on my vps:

```
git clone git://github.com/yasm/yasm.git
cd yasm
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

as for the second error, I also experienced this issue as my */tmp* was mounted with noexec attribute, so to fix this I needed to set TMPDIR to some convenient directory, for example:

```
export TMPDIR=~/mytmp
mkdir -p $TMPDIR
```

once the compilation is completed, you can remove and unset it using

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR
unset $TMPDIR
```

Comment: I installed using these but still i am facing issue

Answer (score 0):

Install dependencies :

```
yum install libvorbis  yasm freetype zlib bzip2 faac lame speex libvpx libogg  libtheora  x264 XviD openjpeg15 opencore-amr
```

Download the tarball from [here](https://libav.org/releases/) and install it:

```
wget https://www.libav.org/releases/libav-10.5.tar.gz
tar xvf libav-10.5.tar.gz
cd libav-10.5
/configure --extra-cflags=-I/opt/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/local/lib --enable-gpl --enable-version3  --enable-libvpx
make
make install
```